# Unable to install tensorflow on oracle server ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, oracle-service-cloud

I created my virtual environment and trying to install tensorflow using **pip install tensorflow**.
am getting the following error :

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I tried it with `python3.8` and `python 3.9` still the same error

Does anyone have any idea how to sort it out?

Comment: Could you add your error stack to the description ? What is the package manager you are using `pip or conda` ?

Comment: yes. am using pip

Comment: Try `pip install tensorflow==2.7.0`.

Comment: still nothing..